# awk concatenate csv column with quotes

Tags: awk

I want to concatenate two columns of a csv file. I have somme issues with the quotes of the csv.

```
"column one","column two","column three"
"A","1","A1"
"B","2","B2"
"C","3","C3"
```

I use this command line:

```
awk -F, '{$2=$3" - "$x;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if(i!=x)f=f?f FS $i:$i;print f;f=""}' x=3 file.csv
```

And the result is:

```
"column one","column two"
"A","1" - "A1"
"B","2" - "B2"
"C","3" - "C3"
```

I want to delete the internal quotes of the column two "3**" - "**C3"

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

with GNU `awk`

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{NF--} {print gensub(/","/," - ",2)}' file

"column one","column two"
"A","1 - A1"
"B","2 - B2"
"C","3 - C3"
```

for the first line, drop the last fields. Otherwise replace the quoted comma with hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\042,\042" }{ $2=$2" - "$3; NF=2 }1' file.csv
```

The output:

```
"A","1 - A1"
"B","2 - B2"
"C","3 - C3"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Gnu sed:

```
sed 's/","/ - /2' file
```

a test:

```
kent$  cat f
"A","1","A1"
"B","2","B2"
"C","3","C3"

kent$  sed 's/","/ - /2' f
"A","1 - A1"
"B","2 - B2"
"C","3 - C3"
```

Comment: Thank you Kent. Keep in mind your soluce but I want to use AWK.